# How to avoid the issue of the account used to join a domain to become a local administrator?

Tags: windows-server-essentials

While joining (for the first time) workstations to the domain provided by our server running Windows Server Essentials, I've encountered the following subtle behavior:

The account that I would use to join the domain, using the Windows Server Connector invariably becomes a member of the Local Administrators group, thus inherits privileges I didn't want it to inherit in first instance.

Basically I first tried to join the workstation using an account from the Domain Administrators group but received a warning from the wizard in using such account, therefore I've used one of the standard account that would be later used by users.

**Question**: shall one use a 'domain-joining-specific' or some 'domain-operator' account for joining a workstation to a domain, or is there a better workflow for such task ?

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with the `Windows Server Connector`, which apparently is a `Server Essentials` feature.  Can't you skip using it, and just join the domain normally?

Comment: Well I guess I could, just tried to follow the 'rules' :D Will give it a try and post my results back here. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connector software does a whole lot of stuff for monitoring, backup VPN etc. Do not bypass it. Use a dedicated account for joining pcs if you don't use a "regular" DA account.

Comment: True, actually the old wizard does not even always work ... I ended up fixing this up by adding a GPO that reconfigures the members of local admins group and it just works :D

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of the wizard.  It should work.